# Migrate Google Calendar to Office 365 Group Calendar

Tags: exchange, google, microsoft-office-365, calendar

I have a Google calendar, with many hundreds of events, well into 2016.

We have just begun to use Office 365 for Education. I have set up a Group in Office 365 via OWA so that all staff can see a shared calendar.

Is it possible (is there a workaround) to import my Google Calendar events into my Office 365 Group shared calendar?

I am able to subscribe to a .ics, but this only adds an additional calendar (still using Google), and doesn't import the events.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37111?hl=en covers the steps required to export one (or all) of your Google calendars to a set of .ics files. You should then be able to import those to the group calendar in Office 365 by importing them into Outlook.